# change filename

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need some help in renaming a large amount of files I am using bash
pretty cutting _Filestore and everything that ends after key and crt in 
files. Thx for your help

---

**Current File**

_Filestore.dev.orange.key_12345_1

_Filestore.dev.orange.crt_57397_1

_Filestore.dev.apple.key_95672566_1

_Filestore.dev.apple.crt_22258_1

**Need it to look like this**

dev.orange.key

dev.orange.crt

dev.apple.key

dev.apple.crt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple straight-forward for-loop. Using `regEx` in `bash` with the `=~` operator (supported from `bash 3.0` onwards) to extract the substring that is need for the file re-naming. You can run this directly on the command line.

```
for file in _Filestore*
do 
    [[ $file =~ ^_Filestore.(.*)_([[:digit:]]+)_([[:digit:]])$ ]] && subString="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    mv -v "$file" "$subString"
done
```

Comment: Thx for your help this pretty muched worked just trying to understand how it works

Comment: @Vegeta: You can read about `regEx` in `bash` from http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_04.html

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
# file.txt
_Filestore.dev.orange.key_12345_1
_Filestore.dev.orange.crt_57397_1
_Filestore.dev.apple.key_95672566_1
_Filestore.dev.apple.crt_22258_1
```

cat file.txt | sed 's/*Filestore.//g' | sed 's/key*.*/key/g' |  sed 's/crt_.*/crt/g' > file2.txt

```
# file2.txt
dev.orange.key
dev.orange.crt
dev.apple.key
dev.apple.crt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in `ls`; do
    echo "the next file is $filename"
    mv $filename `echo $filename | grep -oE "dev.*\...."`
done
```

Get all the files and , rename them using `regex` and `grep`.